# ForkJoinPool.invokeAll(ArrayList<G extends RecursiveTask<T>)

Tags: java, fork-join

I'm trying to invoke a list of `RecursiveTask<Double>` instances on a `ForkJoinPool` using `invokeall()` but it's complaining about the types.

I'm not pretty sure why it's not working.

I have the task classes which are defined as follows:

```
public class WorkerTask<G extends Game> extends RecursiveTask<Double>
```

I create `n` of these tasks and then I would like to let them loose in a `ForkJoinPool`. I know I can invoke them one by one using `pool.invoke(getValue)` but that's not what I want in the end.

The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#invokeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) tell me that it has to be a list of objects that implement `Callable`. I followed the type hierarchy upwards up to `ForkJoinTask`. There I can see a class defined `static final class AdaptedCallable<T> extends ForkJoinTask<T>` so I think it should work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html) ForkJoinTask doesn't implement any Callable interface?

Looking at [this](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2078440/enterprise-java/java-tip-when-to-use-forkjoinpool-vs-executorservice.html?page=2) example I'm not sure you're supposed to be using the invokeAll on the ForkJoinPool. You're supposed to add new WorkerTask to a list in the compute method itself and then call `invokeAll(List<WorkerTask>)`.

Comment: That is correct.  There is a class definition present named `AdaptedCallable`,  so I figured it could work.  I just don't know how.

Comment: AdaptedCallable is an inner class according to http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.html it takes a Callable in it's constructor and doesn't implement any Callable interface. So don't think that's going to work.

Comment: I did what you suggested. I created a task that then subdivides in multiple tasks which I can then `invokeAll()`. Thank you.